# Бот не берет сообщения от юзера телеграм

Tags: python, telebot

Бот не ждет сообщения от пользователя а сразу шлет сообщения об ошибке в чат

вот часть кода отвечающая за это

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['weather'])
def weather(message):
    
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'В каком населённом пункте хочешь узнать погоду?')
    bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
    try:
        mgr = owm.weather_manager()
        observation = mgr.weather_at_place(message.text)
        w = observation.weather
        temp = w.temperature('celsius')['temp']
        today = datetime.datetime.today()

        answer = 'Сегодня, ' + (today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")) + ' ' + 'в городе ' + message.text + ' ' + w.detailed_status + '\n'
        answer += 'Температура в районе ' + str(temp) + ' по Цельсию.' + '\n\n'
        if temp < 5:
            answer += 'Сейчас на улице холодно, одевайся тепло!'
        elif temp < 25:
            answer += 'Сейчас на улице прохладно, одевайся потеплее!'
        else:
            answer += 'Погода просто каеф! Одевайся как душе угодно!'
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, answer)
    except:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Я ещё не знаю такого города \nДавай посмотрим погоду в другом месте?')
```

как заставить его работать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй так

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['weather'])
def weather(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'В каком населённом пункте хочешь узнать погоду?')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_data_weather)


def get_data_weather(message):
    try:
        mgr = owm.weather_manager()
        observation = mgr.weather_at_place(message.text)
        w = observation.weather
        temp = w.temperature('celsius')['temp']
        today = datetime.datetime.today()

        answer = 'Сегодня, ' + (today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")) + ' ' + 'в городе ' + message.text + ' ' + w.detailed_status + '\n'
        answer += 'Температура в районе ' + str(temp) + ' по Цельсию.' + '\n\n'
        if temp < 5:
            answer += 'Сейчас на улице холодно, одевайся тепло!'
        elif temp < 25:
            answer += 'Сейчас на улице прохладно, одевайся потеплее!'
        else:
            answer += 'Погода просто каеф! Одевайся как душе угодно!'
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, answer)
    except:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Я ещё не знаю такого города \nДавай посмотрим погоду в другом месте?')
```

Comment: теперь на try дает инвалид синтаксис

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй переделать и убрать часть, где бот выводит сообщение об ошибке, чтобы тебе напрямую в консоль выводило ошибку. Не делай try и except когда тестируешь прогу.